# sonarqube not showing pom.xml from java project

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, pom.xml

I have an integration of sonarqube, jenkins and bitbucket. I have written custom rules for checking code in java. all my java code when pushed to bitbucket gets detected by jenkins during build process and validated by sonarqube. However the pom.xml doesnt show in the Project of Sonarqube. It shows both in Jenkins and Bitbucket. any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the [XML plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarXML) installed in your SonarQube.
Without that, `.xml` files don't get indexed, analyzed and reported to SonarQube, so `pom.xml` won't appear in the web interface.